# Cumulative distribution function .

Tags: statistics

I have a random variable $X_n = 1+ \frac{1}{n}$ , 
I don't understand completely why the cumulative probability function $F(x)$ is given by $$F(x) = 0 , t < 1+\frac{1}{n}$$ and $$F(x) = 1 , t \ge 1+ \frac{1}{n}$$
. Can someone explain it to me  , specially for $F(x) = 1 $ case .

I know that $$F(x) = \sum_{x_i < x} f(x_i)$$ but using this definition i don't get $1$, rather i get $1+1/n$ .

Comment: What are these $x_i$ that appear in the last formula? If they are the values $X$ can take, the formula should read $$F(x)=\sum_{x_i\leqslant x}P(X=x_i),$$ with $\leqslant$, not $\lt$. In your case, there is only one $x_i$, it is equal to $1+1/n$ and you are told that $P(X=1+1/n)=\color{red}{1}$ hence the sum on the RHS is empty if $1+1/n\gt x$ hence $F(x)=0$, and it is $F(x)=\color{red}{1}$ if $1+1/n\leqslant x$. QED.

Answer (score 1):

Your random variable $X_n$ is in fact a deterministic number, which is equal to $1 + \frac{1}{n}$

So $F(t) = P(X_n \le t) = P(1+\frac{1}{n} \leq t) = \begin{cases}1 &\text{ if } t\geq 1+\frac{1}{n} \\
0 & \text{ if } t < 1+\frac{1}{n} \end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing here with a **constant random variable**.  A random variable is a constant random variable if $P(X=c)=1$ is true for some $c$.

When it is *for certain* that $X$ will take value $c$ then $P(X\leq x)=0$ is true for each $x$ that is smaller than $c$.

In words: it is for certain that $X$ will exceed value $x$ (since it will take value $c$).

Do you agree with that? It can be expressed as $F(x)=0$ if $x<c$ where $F$ denotes the CDF.

And secondly $P(X\leq x)=1$  is true for each $x$ that satisfies $x\geq c$. Simply because it is *for certain* that it will take value $c$. It can be expressed as $F(x)=1$ if $x\geq c$ where $F$ denotes the CDF.

Here *for certain* means actually: with probability $1$.